# IE8 opacity issue using either overlay or blockUI

Tags: internet-explorer, opacity, jquery-tools, blockui

**Would you be very kind and try this in IE8 on your side? Thanks!**

We are using blockUI and are looking into jQuery overlay and we have encountered the same issue with either.

Please do the following

Using IE8 Go to [this page](http://goo.gl/MrjvW), check any checkbox and click download covers.

Please report back if you can see the background or not. If not, let me know if you have an idea of why not. The page in question is using [blockUI v2](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) but we have exactly the same issue with [overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html)

If **I** access the site on a local server using hostfile changes, the opacity of the background works:

[image]

If I however deploy to internet, to the URL given above, the opacity fails for me in IE8 on WinXP SP3:

[image]

In both cases I see `Browser Mode: IE8 | Document mode IE8 Standards` in the developer tools

My `Tools > Compatibility Settings > "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"` is **UN** checked

Answer (score 2):

IE 8 will automatically put the page in compatibility mode if it sees the page as Intr*a*net.

This could certainly be the difference you're seeing.

Comment: I see `Browser Mode: IE8 | Document mode  IE8 Standards` in both situations if that is what you mean. What do YOU see in your IE8?

Comment: It's not.  Tools > Compatibility Settings.  By Default, the option "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" is *enabled*.

Comment: Mine is unchecked. Has been for some time since it bit me last time I had that issue